# How to onBeforeDestroy() ANGULAR

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, destroy, confirmation

Is possible to check when a component is gonna be destroyed but without destroying it before confirmation?

Like when checking route changes.

Comment: You need `canDeactivate` guard. https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

Comment: i was trying with them and finally  GOT IT, i will reply with solution link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897511/how-to-implement-confirm-on-exit-in-angular-4